# AuthorizationFailed when querying flow log status via Azure Rest API

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring

I am trying to **query** the flow logs status for NSG based on docs here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/network-watcher/network-watcher-nsg-flow-logging-rest

but I am getting this exception:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "AuthorizationFailed",
        "message": "The client '4eabxxxx-xxxx-4713-8c17-695fd78e7747' with object id '4eabxxxx-xxxx-4713-8c17-695fd78e7747' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Network/networkWatchers/queryFlowLogStatus/action' over scope '/subscriptions/fe57c71a-xxxx-xxxx-b007-65ae3645bda1/ResourceGroups/networkwatcherrg/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkWatchers/NetworkWatcher_westcentralus'."
    }
}
```

My *application* has "READER" role (also tried with "MONITORING READER" role)

I also tried hitting

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{{subscriptionId}}/providers/Microsoft.Insights/register?api-version=2016-09-01
```

to registered Insights.Provider (mentioned in above docs), but still the same error.

**What are the permissions required to get the flow logs status?**

Comment: I added feature request to Azure team to make Query Flow Log status permission with "/read" action so Reader role which allows "*/read" will automatically allow to call it. Here is the link, please Vote to it, so this query flow log status api will have standard read permission:
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/39562318-additional-read-permission-to-allow-call-to-net

Answer (score 0):

> What are the permissions required to get the flow logs status?

You need the **Query Flow Log Status** permission in Network Watcher.

This permission is in contributor permission actions.

[image]

**Solution:**

1. You can assign a **Network Contributor** role to your application.
2. You can create a custom role with which contains permission and other enough permissions. Then you can assign this role to your applicaiton.

Comment: Hi, @Jatin . Is this answer helpful?

Comment: Thanks for your response! It haven't actually tried it, yet, but it does seem helpful.

Comment: I tried with the permissions you suggested, while I do not get `AuthorizationError` now, I get a `NotFound` error with message `Resource /subscriptions/fe57c71a-xxxx-xxxx-b007-65ae3645bda1/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/xxxxx not found` (while I can clearly see that resource in the portal)

Comment: Hi,@Jatin . Sorry for my late reply. Depending your error massage, Check if the Resource Id is as same as the one in Azure portal.

Comment: If you have any new issue with this, you can also post a new question with more detials.:-)

Answer (score 0):

This is an older API and soon to be deprecated. Please move to the new API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/network-watcher/flowlogs/get

The new API works just with a "Microsoft.Network/networkWatchers/flowLogs/read" permission added at subscription/RG/Resource scope.
SG